# Correct usage with that

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, american-english

> He defined the dandy, in the later "metaphysical" phase of dandyism, as one who elevates æsthetics to a living religion, **that the dandy's mere existence reproaches the responsible citizen of the middle class being "an ordinary, working-class 'anti-star' who nevertheless loves to hog the spotlight**.

Is this not a comma splice? Doesn't the clause starting with that begin an independent sentence. When is that subordinate and when isn't it?

> The secret ingredient used in the recipe. That was the secret to his success.

This would be correct right?

Comment: If you are concerned with correct sentence formation, your example isn't that great since it starts off with an incomplete sentence. ["The secret ingredient used in the recipe." has no verb.]

Comment: Also this sounds like creative writing, in which grammar rules may be bent or broken as the writer sees fit.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a comma splice. The section in bold isn't an independent clause:

> that the dandy's mere existence reproaches the responsible citizen of the middle class being "an ordinary, working-class 'anti-star' who nevertheless loves to hog the spotlight.

This doesn't work on its own.

If you were to remove *that*, however, then it would be an independent clause and you would have a comma splice.

---

The best way to make the sentence grammatical all around is to add something between the comma and the section in bold:

> He defined the dandy, in the later "metaphysical" phase of dandyism, as one who elevates æsthetics to a living religion, ***saying*** **that the dandy's mere existence reproaches the responsible citizen of the middle class being "an ordinary, working-class 'anti-star' who nevertheless loves to hog the spotlight.**

---

Note that there is no closing double quotation mark in the sentence. The grammar aside, that punctuation should be fixed in some way.

Comment: Can that begin a sentence fragment that follows on from an independent sentence if it has a clear antecedent; Is 'that'  similar to a subordinate clause in its usage in my example also?

Comment: @bluebell1 *That* is not being used as a normal pronoun to refer to something specific here. *That you have blue hair is strange* is different from *that is strange*, where it references something previously stated. Both sentences use *that*, but it functions differently.